# htaccess file references going to /etc/apache2, trying to change to relative

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secured"
AuthUserFile ../private/passwd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=unauthenticated
Satisfy any
```

The problem from the `error.log` is that Apache is saying "Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/passwd" - which is obviously my Apache root.

How would I specify a relative reference to the `.htaccess` file for a path instead?

And probably very important, can this be done in the `.htaccess` file only?

If so, answering question #2 would make the solution much more portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doc: [AuthUserFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile)

> The AuthUserFile directive sets the name of a textual file containing the list of users and passwords for user authentication. File-path is the path to the user file. **If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the ServerRoot.**

So I assume that your server root is in `/etc/apache2/` so your relative URL: `./passwd` will be relative to the root, and *not* where your htaccess file is at. Thus, it's not possible to make it portable and relative to where you place the htaccess.

Additionally, the documentation also says:

> **Security**
>
> Make sure that the AuthUserFile is stored outside the document tree of the web-server. Do not put it in the directory that it protects. Otherwise, clients may be able to download the AuthUserFile.

So it's a bad idea to keep your password file in the same place that you serve your content.

Comment: I changed the path to `../private` for the sake of this discussion, even if absolute paths appear to be a hard requirement.